# can't use same i for different tasks,why?

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

using same i for different purpose does'nt seem to work fine,why is that so?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int g,n,i=0,sum;
    cin>>g;
    while(i<g)
    {
        cin>>n;
        int a[n];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin>>a[i];
        for(i=0;i<n;i+=2)
        {    
           "code"
        }
        cout<<sum;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the code didn't worked if m using same i for while as well as for loop,bt it worked if i used different parameter for both.
the task of the parameter is to store the counter.so why its nt working?

Comment: You're using `i` for two different purposes - use two different variables.

Comment: Also `j` is declared in the scope of `main` but is never used there. And the innermost `for`-loop in `main` will make `sum` end up being the sum of the first and the last element of the array `a`. If this is what you want to acheive a loop is not necessary.

Comment: @Anshul Sheoliha What is the meaning of variable g?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow g is for the no. of times the outer loop should work,for test cases.

Comment: @PaulR plz can u tell me why is that so?coz it is used as a counter,then why can't it be used for multiple purposes.

Comment: You can use the same variable for different purposes if you like, but *not at the same time*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as a template for your program the following code. As for errors in your code you can find their descriptions in the comments to your post.:) At least this loop

```
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {    
        sum=a[0];
        sum+=a[i];
    }
```

has no any sense.

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>

void bubblesort( int a[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++ )
        {
            if ( a[j + 1] < a[j] )
            {
                int x = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = x;
            }
        }
    }
}


int main() 
{
    std::cout << "Enter number of elements: ";

    size_t n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;

    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        int *a = new int[n];

        std::cout << "Enter " << n << " integers: ";

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) std::cin >> a[i];

        std::cout << "Original numbers:";
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) std::cout << ' ' << a[i];
        std::cout << std::endl;

        bubblesort( a, n );

        std::cout << "Sorted numbers:";
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) std::cout << ' ' << a[i];
        std::cout << std::endl;

        long long sum = 0;

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) sum += a[i];

        std::cout << "Sum of the numbers is " << sum << std::endl;

        delete [] a;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

if for example to enter

```
10
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

then output will be

```
Original numbers: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
Sorted numbers: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Sum of the numbers is 45
```

Comment: thank you sir,bt i jst wnted to kno that why the outer loop is running only once,even though m giving g any integer greater than 1.I jst edited my question. can u plz tell what could be the reason for while loop..also if m using while(g--) it is working properly.what's the problem with while(i<g).

Comment: @Anshul Sheoliha If you have some problems with other code you should create a thread a new. So mark my answer as the best that to close the thread. As for your new code than it has no any sense. For example variable sum was not initialized and is not cnahged in the code.

Comment: ,i was having problem with the while loop,and not with the bubblesort,although i wna apologize for quoting wrong title for the question earlier..that was regarding bubblesort.So ur answer is for bubblesort. Which too helped me understand the problems in my code. As for te right answer,i gt it myself.

Comment: As i was using same integer i for both the loops,thus the memory for i was allocated for one,so when the inner loop incremented i,the same i is being used in while thus,condition fail after one time the loop is being executed.

Comment: thanks for your help,i got that one.